# Are paramotors a good option for someone interested in flying, if so, what kind of regulations apply to them?

Tags: flight-training, ultralight, cost

I am someone who wants to learn how to fly something, anything that I can ride in because it's just cool, are paramotors cheap and easy to use enough to get from novice to safe pilot in about a year or 2 and how much would it cost? Also what kinds of areas would I have to be in in order to fly it?

Comment: Welcome Ryan!  This is a pretty broad question, and mostly opinion based.  (what's your criteria for cheap and easy?)  As such it really isn't a good fit for this site.  I would suggest finding an on-line community of paramotor enthusiasts and getting involved with them.  P.S. if the goal is to move up to traditional fixed wing aircraft don't see them being a beneficial stepping stone.  Too different.  Probably a fun hobby though, I've never tried.

Comment: @MichaelHall Ok, I'll probably delete this question if you think I should, and I'll try and find a community similar to what you described.

Comment: I wouldn't be too hasty to delete it in case someone can offer something more.  It might be closed by voting though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in the US, paramotors have no license requirements, being treated as recreational vehicles, not aircraft. So you can do whatever you want, although you still have to respect air regulations once airborne, so at minimum you have to learn the "rules of the road".

The main thing is you are flying a wing that is "delicate" in terms of its rigidity, and with an extremely low wing loading, so the physical risks are related to the sensitivity to turbulence and gusts, your legs being the landing gear. Find the most highly rated paramotor school in your area, or travel to one of the top ones, and go get properly trained.

Properly trained, besides learning how to control the thing, is how to assess risk and having the discipline to follow the do's and don'ts. If you watch all the videos of guys flying in convective conditions, or low flying, you have to remember that you have a relatively unreliable 2 stroke motor pushing you along, that might quit at a bad time, and turbulence close to the ground can brake your legs and/or back by smacking you in. Then there's the 3 **BIGGEST** hazards in paramotoring down low, power lines, power lines, and power lines. And also a 4th one, power lines.

Did I mention power lines?

It's a bit like float flying.  Easy to learn to do. The hard part is staying out of trouble, and that takes a lot of mental discipline.